# Google Refresh Token throws Expire Error in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, google-ads-api

```
  UserCredential credential;
      using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
            // authenticated user's account.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
        );
      }
```

Using the code I shared above, I can renew the duration of the refresh token and create a campaign through Google Ads SDK (for Net 5 application) without any problems, but when I launch the same application in Azure Containers, I get a "Token Expire" error.

I will be very happy if you can help me with this behavior difference. Thank you in advance.

Kind regards

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .NET Google Ads SDK, but the documentation of [`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker) states "Do not use this class when executing on a web server, or any cases where the authenticating end-user is not able to do directly interact with a launched browser." Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error **`("Token Expire")`** shows that the Token is expired so you have to check the expiration period or create a new Token.

**You can follow the below step to Refresh auth token**

- When the provider's Access token expires you need to reauthenticate the user before you use it.
- Avoid Token expiration using the GET call to the **`/.auth/refresh`** endpoint of your application.
- When App Service is invoked, the access tokens in the **token store** for the **authorized user** are automatically **refreshed.** Following requests for tokens from your app code, the tokens are updated. However, for a token refresh to work, your provider's refresh tokens must be present in the token storage.
- Append the  `access_type=offline` in a query string parameter to your login API call (`/.auth/login/google`).

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens) for more information